# how to toggleClass for an extented element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, toggle

In this [fiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/x3qwV/2/) When I move my mouse over the black box , a red box should appear but it doesn't .

is this script correct ?

```
$('nav#products ul li div#info').hover(function () {
  $('nav#products ul li div#more_info').toggleClass('show');
});
```

Comment: Your jsFiddle works as expected, adding/removing show class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of [css specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), the ID rule has precedence over class rule - you have an ID rule setting `display: none` then a class rule setting `display:block` but the ID rule will always override the class rule.

You need to combine those two to create a more specific rule to override the ID rule

```
#more_info.show {
    display:block;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3UV8u/)

Also note that since you have ID for the target elements you can use simple ID selectors instead of the more complex selectors used by you - ID of an element must be unique in a document

Comment: yup , that solves the problem and i had to keep the css ids the same i would have to add this in css .

nav#products ul li  div#more_info.show{display:block;}

but ofc your sol. is better and shorter .